# How to change the order of fill aesthetic in faceted ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a faceted `ggplot` that is all but done. I cannot seem to get the fill aesthetic to be descending for each group in the dodged plot and across facets. The idea is to look at the plot and quickly recognise the top three categories within each group on the y-axis - and that the colors will be order different for each group. Here is some code to get a representative graph.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

#using crossing from purrr

df <- crossing(
  mean = 1:8,
  cats = sample(letters[1:3], 8, T), 
  gender = c('Male', 'Female')) %>% 
  mutate(vary_x = sample(seq(1,3,.1),nrow(.), T))


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mean, vary_x, fill = cats))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = 'dodge') +
  facet_grid(.~gender) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mean, reorder(vary_x,mean), fill = cats))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = 'dodge') +
  facet_grid(.~gender) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]